# How to create a TCP bridge / TCP Sniffer for a specific IP and process in c#?

Tags: c#, tcp

I'd like to be able to capture and manipulate TCP packets, which are being sent from a program to a specific IP address. The TCP stream itself is not encrypted or secured, which i've already found out using wireshark.

I already got a program that does so by opening two sockets (one to the client, one to the server), reading all data from one socket and sending it on the other - but it needs to run on a different machine, as i'm using this as a ethernet bridge.

Is there any possibility to run it on one physical machine, so that i can re-route all of the applications traffic through my software proxy?

Comment: Unless you can push all apps to use your proxy, or write a filter driver or use someone else`s, then no. Or potentially write dll inject library that can inject from the kernel, which will likely be crash city.

Comment: Doing this would most likely involve a network filter driver like [winPcap](https://www.winpcap.org/), that is however no longer maintained. c# might not be the best tool to either write such a driver or interact with it since it would involve lots of native code.

Comment: @JonasH There is a library called SharpPcap, which allows to use winPcap (or its successor npcap) in C#.

Comment: Maybe for clarification: I already rerouted all traffic locally by injecting a dll and explicitly setting the target ip to my local proxy, which then routes the traffic to the original target ip. My goal is more a proof of concept to show that you don't need to inject something into the target process.

Comment: @JonasH As far as i'm aware of, winPcap can capture, but not modify packages that are being sent / received, or am i wrong?

Comment: @ElGauchooo I have no real knowledge of the subject. I just wanted to point out that if you are doing low level stuff like this you often need some kind of driver. And drivers usually need native code. You might find existing software that covers your needs, but I'm not familiar enough to provide any recommendations. So I would just check how similar software, like wireshark, work.